# Mongoose update takes a lot of time for large number of input

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I have 1.1 million records in an array. Each record represents a document in mongoDb. I need to update each document in DB through a script.

I created a script and iterated over an array of 1.1 million records and called `mongoose findOneAndUpdate` method. This approach works but it takes a lot of time.

Pseudocode:

```
for(object in array)
 mongoose.findOneAndUpdate({a: object.a}, {b:object.b}) // this runs 11lakh times which is taking a lot of time.
```

Is there a way I can update the records in an time efficient manner?

Comment: Please try to avoid using words like *lakh* that is not globally understood.

Answer (score 0):

Using `bulkWrite` I was able to write records in batches of `100000`.